# How to store result in variable without modifying constant values and data types

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I need solve these two tasks below.

Part 1:

```
+A, B, C = -5, '8', 7.6  # DO NOT MODIFY CONSTANT VALUES
+TOTAL = int()           # DO NOT MODIFY DATA TYPE
+
+''' PSEUDO CODE
+SUM given values of A, B and C as integers, CASTING where necessary.
+STORE result in variable 'TOTAL'.
+
+Expected output:
+    -5 + 8 + 7.6 = 10
+'''
+
+# TODO: implement your solution for pseudo code!
+
+print("{} + {} + {} = {}".format(A, B, C, TOTAL))  # DO NOT MODIFY
```

Here is my solution but I am not quite sure if its the right way to go even though the expected output is correct:

```
import math
A, B, C = -5, '8', 7.6  # DO NOT MODIFY CONSTANT VALUES
B = int(B)
SUM = A + B + C
math.floor(SUM)
TOTAL = int(SUM)           # DO NOT MODIFY DATA TYPE
print("{} + {} + {} = {}".format(A, B, C, TOTAL))  # DO NOT MODIFY
```

Part 2:

```
+TEXT = "I wrote my very first program at age 10!"   # DO NOT MODIFY CONSTANT VALUES
+OUTPUT = str()                                      # DO NOT MODIFY DATA TYPE
+
+''' PSEUDO CODE
+DETERMINE whether 'TEXT' contains the value of 'TOTAL' as substring.
+IF True STORE "true that" in variable 'OUTPUT' ELSE STORE "nope".
+
+Expected output:
+    Value of 'TOTAL' exists in string: true that
+'''
+
+# TODO: implement your solution for pseudo code!
+
+print("Value of 'TOTAL' exists in string: {}".format(OUTPUT))  # DO NOT MODIFY
```

My (probably incorrect) solution:

```
TEXT = "I wrote my very first program at age 10!"   # DO NOT MODIFY CONSTANT VALUES
OUTPUT = str(TEXT[37:39])                           # DO NOT MODIFY DATA TYPE
TEXT = int(OUTPUT)

# result = TEXT.find("10")
# print(result)

if TEXT == TOTAL:
    OUTPUT = "true that"
else:
    OUTPUT = "nope"
print("Value of 'TOTAL' exists in string: {}".format(OUTPUT))  # DO NOT MODIFY
```

As you can see I can't seem to find any other solutions without modifying data types. This assignment is all about simple arithmetics, using only basic operators. No external libraries are needed, nor allowed to be used, for the implementation.

The implementation of the code assignment's second part needs to conform to the pseudo code presented, where strings are supposed to be compared (not numeric values). Also, TEXT needs to be considered a constant (no change to value, nor its data type).

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is a lot of irrelevent information in your question and you don;t really come to a specific question, so there's a good chance this will be closed as 'lacks focus'. You will probably find that your programming improves if you practice distilling your own questions down to the single thing that is causing your problem. In this case I think your question is 'how do I check whether a string contains a substring in Python?' try Googling that.

Comment: By the way in the first question, you have broken the rules by re-assigning B. To be honest it's not an especially well defined problem but my interpretation is that your teacher would also expect the code to work with any of A, B or C being strings. I suspect they also expect each of A, B and C to be cast to integer _then_ summed. Hint: you don't need the math library, the function you need is already in the supplied code.

Answer (score 1):

Answering strictly because I believe there could be value for the poster and other new contributors on the site. Happy to remove my answer if it's not appropriate.

For the first problem there are a lot of different ways to accomplish this same task without modifying the constant values. Here are a couple that come to mind:

```
A, B, C = -5, '8', 7.6
TOTAL = int()

for number in [A, B, C]:
    if type(number) == int:
        TOTAL += number
    else:
        TOTAL += int(number)    
print("{} + {} + {} = {}".format(A, B, C, TOTAL))
```

or

```
A, B, C = -5, '8', 7.6
TOTAL = int()

TOTAL = int(A) + int(B) + int(C)    
print("{} + {} + {} = {}".format(A, B, C, TOTAL))
```

or even

```
TOTAL = A + int(B) + int(C)    
print("{} + {} + {} = {}".format(A, B, C, TOTAL))
```

The issue with all of these is that they don't account for exception-inducing cases where `A`, `B`, or `C` are not able to be (temporarily) converted to an int type. For instance, if instead `B = 'eight'`, this code would raise an exception. The assumption is that this is a lower-level question with hard-coded values so we don't really need to worry about those (for now). So to answer this specific question, the third option will probably be best because it answers the question and only uses casting as necessary.

As an aside: I have a huge preference for the newer way of formatting strings due to the readability, but it doesn't work for all versions of Python. For Python 3.6 and up, you could (perhaps should) use `print(f"{A} + {B} + {C} = {TOTAL}")`

On to Part 2: This is a continuation of the first problem, so we are supposed to assume the variable `TOTAL` already has a value stored (10). So we can use `in` to solve this quite easily.

```
TEXT = "I wrote my first program at age 10!"
OUTPUT = str()

if str(TOTAL) in TEXT:
    OUTPUT = "true that"
else:
    OUTPUT = "nope"

print("Value of 'TOTAL' exists in string: {}".format(OUTPUT))
```

Please let me know if you have any questions about anything here, and welcome to the community!

Comment: Thank you very much for your detalied response. I'm happy that you could provide some clarification on this assignment. I'm also aware of the new way of formatting strings but I just commented it out as I'm not sure if I am allowed to replace it.